# Error TF400018 recurring issue

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, workspace

TF400018: The local version table for the local workspace {PC};{USER} could not be opened. The workspace version table contains an unknown schema version.

Last week, I ran into this issue and followed some of the suggestions on the site of deleting/recreating/remapping the workspace. This seems to work, but only temporarily. Eventually, the workspace will error out and give me the same message (it has happened twice this morning). Anyone have any suggestions? We have several projects and I can't keep remapping everyday due to this error.